# javascript namespace scope

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I'm learning javascript , so don't kill me.
I'm defining more different namespaces like this :

```
var name_Class = function(){
  this.variable_name_1 = {}

  this.method_name_1 = function() {}
}
```

and then..

```
var second_name_Class = function(){
  this.variable_name_1 = {}

  this.method_name_1 = function() {}
}
```

If i define and Initialiaze a variable in the first one and I try to call it in the second one , e.g.  if a write `c = new name_Class()` it , e.g. redefine every array to `[]` so I cannot get the value I gave it before. Can you help me?

Comment: There's no killing here - just asking, answering, and the occasional verbal barb.

Comment: We won't kill you for learning JavaScript. However, we might look with an angry face if we don't understand the question ;). You should really add an example what you actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand what you're doing.

This

```
var name_Class = function(){
  this.variable_name_1 = {}

  this.method_name_1 = function() {}
}
```

defines a constructor function called name_Class (as an aside, constructors should have their first character capitalized by convention)

This

```
var c = new name_Class();
```

creates an object using that constructor.  The new object is created and the constructor is bound to that object and called, setting the variable_name_1 and method_name_1 properties of the new object c.  Each time you assign `new name_Class()` to a variable it will create a completely new object which has the constructor bound to it.  Any changes you made to other objects created to the function will not have an effect on this new variable.

All of this is completely unrelated to your second Constructor, which you can use in the same way and is not affected at all by your first one.

Neither of these things are technically namespaces, they're **classes** or **types**.  A **namespace** generally refers to a top level variable that other variables are defined as properties on.  By default variables are defined on the global namespace, which for browsers is the window.

So to create your new object with type name_Class on a namespace `namespace1` for instance, you could do

```
var namespace1  = {};
namespace1.c = new name_Class();
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Actually I know that I create a new object with that syntax, I have to use namespace syntax so, to retrieve variable value outside of it?

Comment: Sorry, not positive I know what you're asking.  If you want to retrieve one of the internal variables, like variable_name1 in your example, you can call `c.variable_name1` after you've called `var c = new name_Class();`

Answer (score -2):

You can pass in arguments if you're looking to set values on an instance. eg

```
var Swatch = function(){
  this.color = arguments[0] || 'green';
  this.callback = arguments[1] || function() {
     alert(this.color);
  }
  this.callback();
}

//defaults to green if no args are passed
var green = new Swatch();

//or pass in your own values
var red = new Swatch('red',function(){
  alert('New swatch created with color '+this.color);
});
```